# Image array checks

Tags: javascript, arrays, event-handling, html5-canvas

I have multiple image arrays that hold different assets on different canvas layers that will be selected at random and drawn onto a main canvas, but I'm wondering the if its possible to create a callback function to check if one image array is loaded and if it is another one is will not load/draw.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by a callback function? You should just be able to maintain a variable that tells you if a particular array has been loaded.

Comment: Can there be a function that looks to see if a certain array has been loaded and if it has i dont want another array to load.  Maybe its not a callback function maybe im thinking event listner